# Why did my shared_ptr turn into an invalid pointer?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to store in a map some derived classes.

I store them using share_ptr to avoid unexpected deallocation.

Unfortunately, in my attempt it is working-ish: the program compiles and execute but I get an error message.

I obtained the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class DataInOut {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<void> data = nullptr;
    std::type_index type = typeid(nullptr);
    bool initialized = false;
    bool optional = false;

    // template <class Archive>
    virtual bool dummy_funct(int &ar, const char* charName){
        cout<< "serialize_or_throw from DataInOut address is an empty function." << endl; 
        return true;
    }

    DataInOut *clone() const { return new DataInOut(*this); }

    ~DataInOut(){}; // Destructor
};

template <typename T>
class DataInOutType : public DataInOut {
public: 
    // template <class Archive>
    bool dummy_funct(int &ar, const char* charName){
        cout<< "serialize_or_throw from DataInOutTYPE is an FULL function." << endl;
        return true;
    }
}; 

class mapClass {
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<DataInOut> > _m;
    
public:

    template<typename T>
    void set(string key, T* var, bool optional = false) {
        cout << "set entry with " << var << endl;
        std::shared_ptr<DataInOutType<T>> dataIO_ptr (new DataInOutType<T>);
        dataIO_ptr->type = typeid(*var) ;
        dataIO_ptr->data.reset( var ) ;
        dataIO_ptr->optional = optional ;
        dataIO_ptr->initialized = true ;
        _m.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<DataInOutType<T>>>(key, dataIO_ptr) );
        int toto= 1;
        // dataIO_ptr.get()->dummy_funct(toto, key.c_str());
        // cout << "set EXIT" << endl;
    }

    void call_dummy(string key){
        int dummyArchive= 1;
        _m.at(key).get()->dummy_funct(dummyArchive, key.c_str());
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    mapClass mapTest;
    double length = 1.0;

    mapTest.set("length", &length);
    cout << "mapTest is out of set" << endl;
    mapTest.call_dummy("length");

    cout << "ByeBye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then using the compilation line:

```
g++ -std=c++17 ./test.cpp -o prog && ./prog
```

I obtain the following output:

```
Hello World!
set entry with 0x7ffcda122318
mapTest is out of set
serialize_or_throw from DataInOutTYPE is an FULL function.
ByeBye!
free(): invalid pointer
Abandon
```

So my question is how to prevent from the invalid pointer ?

Comment: What are you attempting when you put the address of local variable `double length` in a `std::shared_ptr`?  That would be the invalid pointer you are trying to free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line:

```
mapTest.set("length", &length);
```

You are calling `set()` with a raw `double*` pointer to a local variable `length` that was not allocated with `new`.  Internally, `set()` is assigning that raw pointer as-is to a `shared_ptr` in the `map`.  When that `shared_ptr` is destroyed later, it will try to call `delete` on that `double*` pointer, but since the `double` it points to was not allocated with `new` to begin with, you get the runtime error.

This is why mixing raw pointers with smart pointers without clear ownership semantics is very dangerous.  Use raw pointers only for non-owning views into existing data.  Use smart pointers when allocating data dynamically.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class DataInOut {
public:
    shared_ptr<void> data = nullptr;
    type_index type = typeid(nullptr);
    bool initialized = false;
    bool optional = false;

    // template <class Archive>
    virtual bool dummy_funct(int &ar, const char* charName){
        cout<< "serialize_or_throw from DataInOut address is an empty function." << endl; 
        return true;
    }

    virtual shared_ptr<DataInOut> clone() const { return make_shared<DataInOut>(*this); }

    virtual ~DataInOut() = default; // Destructor
};

template <typename T>
class DataInOutType : public DataInOut {
public: 
    // template <class Archive>
    bool dummy_funct(int &ar, const char* charName){
        cout << "serialize_or_throw from DataInOutTYPE is an FULL function." << endl;
        return true;
    }

    shared_ptr<DataInOut> clone() const override { return make_shared<DataInOutType<T>>(*this); }
}; 

class mapClass {
private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<DataInOut> > _m;
    
public:

    template<typename T>
    void set(const string &key, shared_ptr<T> var, bool optional = false) {
        cout << "set entry with " << var.get() << endl;
        auto dataIO_ptr = make_shared<DataInOutType<T>>();
        dataIO_ptr->type = typeid(T);
        dataIO_ptr->data = var;
        dataIO_ptr->optional = optional;
        dataIO_ptr->initialized = true;
        _m[key] = dataIO_ptr;
        int toto = 1;
        // dataIO_ptr->dummy_funct(toto, key.c_str());
        // cout << "set EXIT" << endl;
    }

    void call_dummy(const string &key){
        int dummyArchive = 1;
        _m.at(key)->dummy_funct(dummyArchive, key.c_str());
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    mapClass mapTest;
    auto length = make_shared<double>(1.0);

    mapTest.set("length", length);
    cout << "mapTest is out of set" << endl;
    mapTest.call_dummy("length");

    cout << "ByeBye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/YZdSm2)